# Need Help with 8x12 Register Vent in Primary Bedroom

Tags: vent, air, register

Our primary bedroom currently has the worst cooling performance of all our rooms. It's farthest from the system and also gets the most sunlight. Our vent in this room is 8 x 12, and also sits on the ceiling. I am trying to do one of two things to get a vent fan installed:

1. Find a 8 x 12 register/vent fan, [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HYJXWKL) but just a couple inches bigger.
2. Find a register/vent wall adapter plate, [like this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Suncourt-Flush-Fit-Booster-Adaptor-Plate-in-White-HC5PL1-W/202803692?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D26P-026_002_AIR_CIRC_ACC-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-4061067-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PL3_PMax&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D26P-026_002_AIR_CIRC_ACC-NA-NA-NA-PMAX-4061067-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PL3_PMax-71700000103189470--&gclid=Cj0KCQjwho-lBhC_ARIsAMpgMocpkmLu4fzgE9wpI3Crh0cygum7VB6gXeE7drqFkhyfv7NeGLD28VgaAofrEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds), to make the opening smaller so that I can use a fan like the one linked in #1

The problem is that for the life of me, I cannot find either one of the two things above. I can find products that fit vents up to 6 x 12, but not any smaller. If anyone can help me with either of the two things listed above, or help in another way that might solve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Might want to adjust the ducts to provide more air to that room, or instead of a register fan use a duct fan for more air.  Blocking sun from hitting the window will help also.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from using the 6x12 and patching the other 2" with carpet/floor/drywall?

Comment: Is the nearest outlet less than 12' from the vent, along ceiling and wall?

Comment: @crip659 I'm looking into that option as well, it's a little more invasive and not the ideal route but might have to be the solution depending on what we can do

Comment: @cheery.beach7701 another option for sure. I've never done that but it might be the best route

Comment: @Huesmann it is, yes. Not by much but within that length!

Comment: @hailthemitten do you have access to the duct above the ceiling, or is there another floor above the MBR?